# Explanation of block systems and group action

Tags: group-theory, set-partition

According to Wikipedia:

"If $B$ is a block then $gB$ is a block for any $g$ in $G$. If $G$ acts transitively on $X$, then the set $\{gB \mid g \in G\}$ is a block system on $X$."

i.e., $\{gB \mid g \in G\}$ partitions $X$.

I am trying to understand how you can go about proving this statement.  I understand that the existence of a block system in $X$ defines partitions in $X$, but how can you deduce from that a group action also leads to partitions?

Comment: If $G$ acts transitively on $X$, then $\cup_{g \in G} gB = G$. (That would true for any nonempty subset $B$ of $X$.) On the other hand, if $B$ is block then, by definition of a block, two sets $g_1B$ and $g_2B$ are either equal or disjoint, so the distinct sets $gB$ must partition $X$.

Comment: Thank you! (I'm not sure if there's a way to make your comment the accepted answer)